# Generate Places Api key Without having WebSite

Tags: android, google-api, google-places-api, google-api-console

I am creating one small application in android and learning everything.

In my application i am going to use google places api for that i must have to generate my api key.

And as we know it requires organization name and website url.

I can provide organization name but what the solution in case of website url if i am not having any website my own.

Here i am also sharing the snapshot.

[image]

**So my question is how can i generate key without having website?**

Comment: unable to understand.Can you elaborate what you mean to say?

Comment: @Triode One more thing is it possible to use same api key for google maps api v2 and google places? i mean to say i generated one key for my application for google maps api v2 can i use the same key to access the google places api?

Comment: Nirav, did you ever find answers to these questions? I am in same situation.

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same situation. I just simply put "Personal Use - iOS development course" in "Company or Organization" field and the link to my Google+ URL in the "Website URL" field. It was instantly granted access, and I have had no issues yet.

If you will be using it recreationally and will stay within the 1,000 requests/day free usage tier, a link to the organization's presence on any social media platform should suffice.